# error code ggplot2: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the dataframe form the picture included with the following code, but I keep obtaining an error and a weird view of the dataframe in the plot.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPl8n.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmlEw.png)

```
df = data.frame(Years = rownames(indexes), indexes[,])
df = melt(df, id.vars = "Years")
colnames(df)[2] = "Countries"
colnames(df)[3] = "Index"
ggplot(df, aes(x = Years, y = Index, color = Countries)) + 
geom_line()
```

I tried the 'group =' argument in the ggplot function, but that shows an even weirder view..

=>

UPDATE:

```
df = data.frame(Years = rownames(indexes), indexes[,])
df = melt(df, id.vars = "Years")
colnames(df)[2] = "Countries"
colnames(df)[3] = "Index"
ggplot(df, aes(x = Years, y = Index, color = Countries, group = Countries)) + 
geom_line()
```

The graph shows, but the y-axis is not formatted as I want it to (only discrete values from 2:7 instead of showing all values between the min and max of the dataframe with 7digits) [UPDATED GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UOzX.png)

Comment: From the Image of your plot I would guess that `Index` isn't a numeric but a character instead, i.e. check your data and convert to a numeric. Also, from the Image I would guess that `Years` is a character too in which case you have to convert to a numeric too or explicitly set the `group` aes, i.e try `ggplot(df, aes(x = Years, y = Index, color = Countries, group = Countries))`.

Comment: Thank you stefan, I added the 'group = Countries' argument and the graph shows now, the y-axis is still showing all values just like the picture above. The values are numeric, so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: Have you checked that it is numeric, i.e. `class(df$Index)`?

Comment: You are right, the Index was indeed of data type character, while the initial dataset is not. Thank you!